# Updating slider value with Swift UI

Tags: swiftui, wrapper

I'm trying to pass data from one view to another and update the slider.

I understand you can do this with @State and @Binding property wrappers however it does not appear to be updating.

On my content view I have:

```
@State var startNumber: Double = 0
@State var endNumber: Double = 5000

Slider(value: $startNumber, in: 0...10000, step: 0.1)
```

On my second view I have:

```
@Binding var startNumber: Double
@Binding var endNumber: Double
@State var number: String = ""
@State var number2: String = ""

FirstResponderTextField(text: $number2, placeholder: "\(endNumber)")
Button(action: {
            startNumber = Double(number) ?? 0
            endNumber = Double(number2) ?? 0
            print("\(startNumber)")
            print("\(number)")
            print("\(endNumber)")
            print("\(number2)")
            self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        }
```

I can see that the value doesn't update the @Binding as it stays at 0.

So I can't even get the variable to update, would someone know why?

Then I understand for the value to show on the content view that I would need to call onAppear after the Hstack for it to show the updated value?

```
HStack {

}onAppear {
  self.startNumber = $startNumber 
}
```

However, this doesn't seem to work either?

Comment: How do you present second view from first view (this can be important)?

Comment: Works fine just between two views in on hierarchy, so, as I wrote above, it depends on how do you present second view. Binding might be unreliable between two different view hierarchies... or some other code affects.